# Convert List<oneType> to IEnumerable<anotherType>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, type-conversion, ienumerable

I have a `listAdoParams` which is a `List<AdoNetAppenderParameter>`.

**AdoNetAppenderParameter** being a type in the **log4net** library.

```
namespace log4net.Appender
{
  public class AdoNetAppenderParameter
    {
    public AdoNetAppenderParameter();
    public DbType DbType { get; set; }
    public IRawLayout Layout { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public byte Precision { get; set; }
    public byte Scale { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public virtual void FormatValue(IDbCommand command, LoggingEvent loggingEvent);
    public virtual void Prepare(IDbCommand command);

    }
}
```

I would like to convert this `listAdoParams` to `IEnumerable<IDataParameter>`.

```
namespace System.Data
{
  public interface IDataParameter
    {
    DbType DbType { get; set; }
    ParameterDirection Direction { get; set; }
    bool IsNullable { get; }
    string ParameterName { get; set; }
    string SourceColumn { get; set; }
    DataRowVersion SourceVersion { get; set; }
    object Value { get; set; }
     }
}
```

How should I do this conversion?

Comment: "An application does not create an instance of the IDataParameter interface directly, but creates an instance of a class that inherits IDataParameter." [...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idataparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll need a class that inherits from IDataParameter in order to convert the log4net type.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to produce a one-for-one projection of one type onto another type is to execute a `Select`. If the new type is an interface, you have to make an implementation of that interface first:

```
class MyDataParameter : IDataParameter {
    DbType DbType { get; set; }
    ParameterDirection Direction { get; set; }
    bool IsNullable { get; }
    string ParameterName { get; set; }
    string SourceColumn { get; set; }
    DataRowVersion SourceVersion { get; set; }
    object Value { get; set; }
}

var res = initial.Select(
    p => new MyDataParameter {
        DbType = p.DbType
    ,   ParameterName = p.ParameterName
    ,   ... // and so on
    }
).Cast<IDataParameter>();
```

Another way would be to wrap `AdoNetAppenderParameter` in an instance of `MyDataParameter`:

```
class MyDataParameter : IDataParameter {
    private readonly AdoNetAppenderParameter wrapped;
    public MyDataParameter (AdoNetAppenderParameter w) {
        wrapped = w;
    }
    DbType DbType {
        get { return wrapped.DbType; }
        set { wrapped.DbType = value; }
    }
    ... // And so on
}
```

Now the projection would look simpler:

```
var res = initial.Select(p => new MyDataParameter(p)).Cast<IDataParameter>();
```

Comment: Can the [MyDataParameter] class contain the extra fields like [Precision], [Scale] etc. so that they are also part of the target mapping?

Comment: @GilliVilla `MyDataParameter` class is hidden. The idea is to access it only through the `IDataParameter` interface. Adding properties or methods to it is allowed, in this situation it would be useless: nobody who sees only a `IDataParameter` would be able to access the additional properties for `Precision`, `Scale`, and so on.